# Entity Framework : can't add multiple entities on post

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api

Trying to insert an entity that embeds another one, I got this error :

> The instance of entity type 'Tache' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.'

C# model :

```
public class Mission
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateDebut { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFin { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tache> Taches { get; set; }

    public string Client { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<MissionComp> Competences{ get; set; }
}
```

Post function :

```
public Mission Post([FromBody]Mission mission)
{
        try
        {
            context.Tache.AddRange(mission.Taches);
            //context.SaveChanges();
            context.Add(mission);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return mission;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
}
```

Already searched for some answer on stack overflow and git but none helps me.
If anyone has an idea I'll be really interested in :D

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

Got something interesting here, I'm sending an array of 'Tache' but the Id is the same for the two so I think they collide : https://puu.sh/vLqTE/52fb2059bc.png

Maybe does someone know how to set temporary key that not collide ?

Comment: If the relationship between `Mission` and `Tache` is setup correctly, you shouldn't need to add the taches separately - adding the `Mission` should be enough.
This may be the source of your error - when you add the `Mission` it's trying to add the taches again?

Comment: Exactly the same error @christophano

Comment: Presumable these are new items, so the id is `0` - is your entity configuration set to assign db identity to these keys?

Comment: Normally yes (at least on an other identity it runs like this) but in case, how do I verificate ? @christophano

Comment: That depends how you're configuring your entities. Doe the `Tache` object also have the `[Key]` attribute applied to its `Id` property?

Comment: `public class Tache
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public string TacheString { get; set; }
    }` @christophano

Comment: on the sql schema (or in the migrationxxx.cs), is the Tache.Id column an identity column ?

Comment: https://puu.sh/vKDBd/3ceb2f3886.png (this is an image :D)

Comment: not enough (we need the property of the id column). BTW are you in code first or database first mode ? Or what is the result of the following query `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('NomDeLaTable')`

Comment: I'm in code first (and kinda new on it)

Comment: Does this help ? https://puu.sh/vKEcC/2cd0d19eb9.png

Comment: It looks like the identity option isn't being specified. Try manually specifying your keys as identity firleds by adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` as an attribute.

Comment: no :). Give us the result of the givent sql query.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, does this help @tschmit007 ? https://puu.sh/vLpLl/67fd12997b.png

Comment: Post edited, got something interesting @tschmit007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found it myself that for an unknow reason all my object in my list had the same Id ... for a stupid reason :

```
public addSousMission() {
        let tache: Tache = {
             Id: 1,
             TacheString: this.champTache
        }

        tache.TacheString = this.champTache;

        this.mission.Taches.push(tache);
        this.champTache = '';
    }
```

Modified to this resolve all my problems :

```
public addSousMission() {
        let tache: Tache = new Tache();

        tache.TacheString = this.champTache;

        this.mission.Taches.push(tache);
        this.champTache = '';
    }
```

Thanks for the help :D